# How to create HTML5 data attribute in an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to pull the innerText of an H1 (which isn't in the iframe and has the "product name" in it) into the  of a form button that is in an owned iframe (not-3rd party). This is my code below, which obviously isn't working. 
Thank you in advance!

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

var productName = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].getAttribute("innerHTML");
var links = document.querySelectorAll("input");
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].dataset.productName = productName;
}

</script>
```

Comment: `var productName = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].textContent`;

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `getAttribute("innerHTML")` do `document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML`. That will get you the actual product name.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.frameElement.getAttribute('data');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

var productName = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerText;
var links = window.frames['<your iframe name>'].document.querySelectorAll("input");
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].dataset.productName = productName;
}

</script>
```